# Calculating sums of columns in CSV file using C++

Tags: c++, csv

How can I calculate sums of columns from CSV file using C++?

My csv file

```
22 45  33
8  50  70
4  60  88
```

And I want the result in an array some thing like this

```
34 155 190
```

can i add a formula in a csv file using c programming

Comment: So you want to get the sum value of each column across all the rows of a CSV file?  Your example is confusing, since 33+70+88 != 170.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes sir i want to sum each column across each row

Comment: That's not a CSV file. That's a space-separated columnar format.

Comment: sir i have written this data in a csv file

Comment: Errr... 33+70+88 isn't 190 either.  Try 191.

Comment: sir i have write 190 some one else has edit it and thats not the point

Comment: My point was your example wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Store the sum in an array:

```
int val;
int sum[column];

for each row in csv file
    for each column i in csv file
        val = atoi(read_value_from_file())
        sum[i] += val
    end for
end for
```

Comment: Only one dimension is needed in the array, containing the running total of reach column. Each time a row is read, add the columns to the running totals in the array.

Comment: @tariq: here it is. @Mike DeSimone: yup, I had two arrays since the OP may need the single values later

Comment: sir blackbear how would my file know that i want to retrieve value from j col and i row

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::ifstream in;
    int array[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    if (argc < 2)
        return 1;

    in.open(argv[1], std::ifstream::in);
    while (in.good()) {
        int one, two, three;
        in >> one >> two >> three;
        array[0] += one;
        array[1] += two;
        array[2] += three;
    }

    std::cout << array[0] << ' ' << array[1] << ' ' << array[2] << std::endl;
    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: thanks sir for yoour reply sir kindly tell me what is good() never heard about that and also i have many column in my file how to add them across the row ie add values in first column then jump to secoond column then 3rd. so on

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/
It will read whole file, doesn't matter how many rows It has.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the table in a 2D array and then you can calculate the sum of elements in columns using simple for loop.
Check *[this](https://github.com/abhinav1602/.csv-to-.cpp-2D-Array)* repository for getting code for the same.
Hope it helps.